# "would not have been possible VS. "was not possible "

Tags: comparison

> 1. My curriculum was too busy and **it would not have been** possible to put any extra activity to it.

> 2. My curriculum was too busy and **it was not** possible to put any extra activity to it.

Do these two sentences have any nuanced difference in terms of the meaning that they convey to a native English speaker? What are the differences?

Answer (score 1):

The choice of tense in OP's example is effectively arbitrary and makes no difference to the meaning in most cases.

Rarely, introducing the modal *(**would not have been**)* rather than Simple Past *(**was not**)* might imply the speaker never actually made any attempt to do something (because he knew it wouldn't work anyway), as opposed to having made the attempt and failed.

But if it was important to make the above distinction you'd probably want to use more words to remove any potential ambiguity. Compare *That **isn't / won't be** possible* when being refused permission for something (usually both tenses are equivalent).

Answer (score 0):

“Would have been impossible” - I did not try seriously. But if I had tried, I would have failed.

“Was impossible” - I tried and I failed.